# select in table where list<int>

Tags: c#, search

There is a table with field age and name

The following data

```
jack 15
sara 14
mishel 13
sufia 19
green 22
blue 56
```

We have a presentation  with the following  members

```
list<int> age = new list<int>(); 
age.add(15);
 age .add(14);
 age .add(19);
```

How do I search the database by providing

The following are selected data from Table

```
jack 15
sara 14
sufia 19
```

Comment: What does `How do I search the database by providing` mean?

Comment: This question is too vague. What kind of database is this? Do you already have a database access strategy? Please see the [faq] and [ask] and the related links on those pages.

Answer (score 5):

Build a SQL query programmatically using the `IN` clause:

```
string sql = @"
    SELECT *
      FROM [PeopleTable]
     WHERE [Age] IN (" + age.Join(", ") + ")";
```

Result:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [PeopleTable]
 WHERE [Age] IN (15, 14, 19)
```

Comment: @jackStonre: How are you using the Stored Procedure?  Are you passing a list of ages?  A table of ages?  A comma-separated string?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MSSQL you can create a table type which will have one column as Age.

```
CREATE TYPE my_table_type AS TABLE(Age int NOT NULL)
go

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_FetchUser
 @age my_table_type READONLY 
AS
select user_name from my_table where user_age in( select * from @age)
go
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use LINQ to SQL, then you should create this query:

```
var query = from record in table
            where ages.Contains(record.age)
            select record;
query.ToList();
```

If you want to use SP, then you gotta create the where clause dynamically:

```
string whereClause = string.Empty;
foreach (int age in ages)
{
    whereClause += age + ", ";
}
whereClause = whereClause.SubString(query, query.Length - 2) // Removing the last comma;
string query = string.Format ("select * from tableName where age in ({0})", whereClause);
```